# What command in a SCRIPT will cause the next "ls" to list the files IMMEDIATELY?

Tags: ls, performance

**Summary**

What command can I run in a bash script that will make the next `ls` at a
terminal list the files in a directory immediately, instead of having to wait 10
seconds?

And see Questions 1 and 2 at end of "Full Details".

**Full Details**

I've got 700 video files (mp4) in a directory, ranging in size from 100 MB to
1GB. The average file size is 200 MB.

When I list them for the first time after boot (using ls in a terminal, or using
pcmanfm), it takes 10 seconds before the files are listed. Thereafter, when I
list them again (with ls or in pcmanfm), the files are listed almost
immediately.

So to try and get round this initial wait time, I ran the following command in a
script after bootup:

```
ls /path/to/vid-directory
```

... so that thereafter, when I list the directory with ls or in pcmanfm, the
files list immediately.

But strangely, running

```
ls /path/to/vid-directory
```

in the SCRIPT does NOT cause the NEXT ls or pcmanfm to list the files
immediately (they're listed after 10 seconds). Also strangely, when the initial
script runs, the files are listed almost immediately.

So, running ls at a terminal seems to store the filenames in RAM cache, whereas
running ls in a script does not*.

**Question 1:** Why is the latter* happening?

**Question 2:** What command(s) should I run in my script that WILL cause the
next ls or pcmanfm to list the files immediately?

PS: Whilst doing the testing, I made sure that RAM was initially empty by
running

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

Comment: What is the actual size of the directory itself? Did it once contain a huge number of files? After I flush caches, I can `ls -lR` about 1000 files a second.

Comment: Can you please add some information about your operating system, the media your data is on (HDD/SSD? USB drive? Network file system?) and the file system you are using? Similarly to what Paul_Pedant says, I see `ls` listing ~1000 files/second from a USB 3 spinning HDD (~6000 files, ~500GB in total).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant: Part 1 of 2: The directory with the 700 vids in is 135 GB in size.
There are also 13 subdirectories (not nested), so the TOTAL size (including the
just-mentioned directory) is 212 GB. My thinking is that the content of those
subdirectories is not involved in the time it's taking ls to do the listing. The
"ls /path/to/vid-directory" lists the files in the first directory, plus just
the names of the subdirectories.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant: Part 2 of 2: I wouldn't say the first directory (the one with 700
files in) once contained a huge number of files (nor the subdirectories). My
guesstimate is that it might have once contained 1100 files (vids). My instinct
tells me that the behaviour isn't to do with some kind of "fault", but I could
be wrong.

Comment: The actual file data size would never affect ls. For a short listing, it scans the entire directory (that is, just the list of names and inode numbers) once. It sorts it, so it can't write the first name until it reads the last. For a long listing, it also reads the inode, which is one block per file, and contains dates, sizes, permissions and timestamps. I'm wondering whether your PATH is overloaded -- maybe an early directory in there has a huge number of files. Bash hashes command names to avoid multiple searches: that would fit with different bash processes having an initial delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only plausible difference between `ls` in a terminal and `ls` in a script is that you've aliased `ls` to pass an option that requires it not only to read the list of file names, but also to read the file's attributes. The option is probably `--color`. Reading the list of file names only requires reading from the directory itself, whereas reading the file's attributes requires accessing each individual file's inode (with an `lstat` system call). So when you run `ls` in that script, only the file names end up in the cache, not their attributes. The first time you run `ls` in the terminal or use a GUI file manager, the attributes need to be loaded.

Pass the same options to `ls` in your script that you use on the terminal.

10 seconds to list only 700 files is abnormally slow though. The size of the files is irrelevant. Typical modern systems only start getting noticeably slow with tens or hundreds of thousands of files if not more.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out what the problem is by running after a reboot:

```
strace -tt -o ls.strace ls /path/to/directory
```

The output of `ls` can be accelerated by `ls -U` but, of course, that does change the output.

700 files is not a large number. Some acceleration may be achieved by rewriting all the directory entries:

```
mkdir /tmpdir/on/the/same/filesystem
mv * /tmpdir/on/the/same/filesystem
mv /tmpdir/on/the/same/filesystem/* .
```

But the most effective solution may be to have the directory be read automatically in the background at boot.